# Multithreading and Synchronization

Tags: synchronized

I have been trying to understand the real reason for using synchronization in a multithread code.

We know if multiple threads access a common shared resource at the same time, will results in many issues like deadlock, racing condition etc. but if we synchronize a code which is called by multiple threads, it would allow only one thread to access the resource and other threads will wait in queue. if this is the case, then this is as good as a single thread application without synchronization. what performance gain that we will get if we synchronize a multithreaded code?

just an example to compare two scenarios
1. we have to process 1000 records in a single thread model assuming that it takes 1 second to process a single record, so totally it takes 1000 seconds to complete.
2. we have to process 1000 records in a multi thread model with the process method is synchronized assuming that it takes 1 second to process a single record and lets say 10 threads are spawned, so here as well, wheneve a thread gets access to synchronized method, rest of the threads will be in queue, totally it takes 1000 seconds to complete.

I would be really satisfied and relieved if someone could make me understand this basic. thanks,

### Edit:

I haven't mentioned the programming language: Its Java

### Just to understand the impact of synchronization and without synchronization for the below code (Spring Batch Example):

```
package com.dbas.core;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;

public class NextReader implements ItemReader<String> {       
    private List<String> itemList;
    public NextReader(ListBean listBean) {
        itemList = listBean.getItemList();
    }
    public synchronized String read()
    {           
        if (!itemList.isEmpty()) {
                  return itemList.remove(0);
        }
        return null;
    }   
}
```

---

Do we have to sychronize the above code? if not, the instance variable "itemList" will be shared across multiple threads, if shared, will the above item retrieval works properly?
There will be a Processor gets called after read() which process the items. is it advicable to synchronize the above code for multiple threads or will it work without any issue without synchronization?

Thanks.

Comment: Although their is a generic answer like @Claudio ... the answer is also highly dependent on what programming platform. Its sounds like your using the JVM?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if the time you keep the mutex is very long compared to the rest of the code, then you lose the benefits of multithreading. As an extreme, consider an application where a thread keeps the mutex forever: you get a single thread application!

For this reason, software developers usually design the code so that you keep the lock for the shortest time as possible. See, for example, the double checked locking pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

For more complex situations, there exist data structures that allow to have good performance even when there are several threads that read and write data. See, for example, the RCU data structure, implemented also in the Linux kernel: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update

Answer (score 0):

You are right that if the entire process is synchronized, it would take the same time no matter how many threads there are.(In reality, it would take longer time the more threads there are due to the overhead of context switching and other things).

The clue then is to not synchronize an entire process method in such a case. 
Ideally processing one message would be totally independent of processing another message, in that case you could in theory process 1000 messages concurrently, and it would take 1000 times less time, given you have 1000 processors at your disposal.

In practice, you end up somewhere inbetween. You might use many small locks, each covering code and data that are independent of each other. Or you might keep all the data for each message independent of each other, requiring no synchronization for that part, but as the main processing is done, you need to insert the result in a shared array - where you need locks around access to that shared array.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization in multithreaded code is used to enable safe shared state access of resources between different threads. Accessing shared state by many different threads, depending on the language and hardware implementation details, has the following hazards:

1. Data corruption, when two threads concurrently attempt to read / write the same memory location.
2. Visibility side-effects, when one thread changes the state of a shared resource then changes may not become apparent to other threads immediately (or even at all) without proper synchronization. This may also happen due to compiler optimizations (instruction re-ordering)

Having said that your question is vague, you mention the word "synchronized" by not any specific programming language. In Java, the word syncrhonized in various contexts means an implicit monitor / lock and too many locks could be a bad thing for performance, there are uses cases where fine grained locking or non-blocking algorthims / [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) strategies offer better performance. The topic is very broad and you ll have to be more specific.

edit: In the scenario that you describe, if all work is completely serial and all state is shared then there could be little or no benefit in a multithreaded implementation. However such extremes are rare, often a portion of the task can be run in parallel and then you can have a measurable performance improvement. [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) can be used to find the theoritical maximum performance benefit when trying to parallelize a task.

edit:

Regarding your edit, since i happen to have used Spring Batch i can tell you for sure that if you are using a thread pool to read items from the list you have to use synchronization and you can do it in many ways, below you can see two of them:

```
public class NextReader implements ItemReader<String> {
    private List<String> itemList;
    private AtomicInteger current = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public NextReader(ListBean listBean) {
        itemList = listBean.getItemList();
    }

    public syncronized String read() {
        int index = this.current.getAndIncrement();
        if (index < itemList.size()) {
            return itemList.get(index);
        } else
            return null;
    }   
}
```

or

```
public class NextReader implements ItemReader<String> {
    private List<String> itemList;
    private AtomicInteger current = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public NextReader(ListBean listBean) {
        itemList = listBean.getItemList();
    }

    public syncronized String read() {
        int index = this.current.getAndIncrement();
        if (index < itemList.size()) {
            return itemList.get(index);
        } else
            return null;
    }   
}
```

They both have the same effect, that is they allow you to read from itemList using multiple on a thread safe manner.

Comment: Thanks all for the replies!